# App shouldnt get uninstall normally

Tags: android

I am using an app where I am storing the data in sqlite. So, my app shouldn't get uninstall normally. Only administrator can be able to uninstall it. So how can I provide security to stop my app from getting uninstalled. Is there a way that only administrator can uninstall the app? If yes, please help me. I am new to android.

Comment: you can't, android give not permission to developer for this

Comment: Then how can i stop the app to get uninstalled.

Comment: you can't dear,say your boss , not possible

Answer (score 1):

That isn't possible, there is nothing like an administrator on Android and also no way for developers to change the way their app is unistalled. Main reason for that is that it would be too much of a security problems if you could simply block an app from being uninstalled.